# Setting colnames of several data frames based on a list variable

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, names

I have a list of multiple data frames which are built the same way. I would like to change the name of the 1 column of each data frame to the name of the data frame itself and append some text. From several different answers I figured lapply and working on lists would be the best way to go.

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)

col1 <- names(dfList)

df<-lapply(dfList, function(x) {
names(x)[1:2] <- c(col1[1:length(col1)]"appended text","Col2","Col3");x
})
```

The problem seems to be with calling the correct entry in the "col1" variable for each data frame within my code.
Any ideas on how I should address/ express this correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the correct output you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1<-data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2<-data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
dfList <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2)
names(dfList)
col1 <- names(dfList)

for(i in 1:length(dfList))
  names(dfList[[names(dfList[i])]])[1]<-names(dfList)[i]

dfList
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(dfList, ~ .x %>%
                rename(Aappended_text = A))
```

If this is based on the column index, create a function

```
fName <- function(lst, new_name, index){
      map(lst, ~ 
               .x %>%
                  rename_at(index, funs(paste0(., new_name))))

 }

fName(dfList, "appended_text", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your quesiton completely but is tihs what you're after:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)

df <- lapply(dfList, function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- c(paste0(colnames(x)[1], "appended text"), colnames(x)[2:length(colnames(x))])
  return(x)
})
```

Output:

```
> df
[[1]]
  Aappended text B C
1              1 2 3

[[2]]
  Aappended text B C
1              1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `lapply`

```
lapply(dfList, function(x) {
  names(x)[1L] <- "some text"
  x
})
```

But if you want to rename by the name of the data frame elements in your list, first you need to name them e.g. `dfList <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)` and you can't acces them directly with `lapply(x, ...` so you need to `lapply`over your list by indexes, for example :

```
lapply(seq_along(dfList), function(i) {
  names(dfList[[i]])[1L] <- names(dfList[i])
  dfList[[i]]
})
```